# How do I fix my error saying the home directory is invalid?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm still learning how to work with bash but my program is part of part 1 which is posted below but they are wanting us to use the file `cs.rosters.txt` to generate the `new_users.txt` file.

The `cs.rosters.txt` looks like this:

```
   CMPSC 1513 03|doejan|Doe, Jane|0510|0350
   CMPSC 1513 03|smijoh|Smith, John|0510
   CMPSC 1133 01|cp2stu3| CPII, Student3 Neither|2222|0020
```

Below is what I created for part 1 which runs correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f1)
  GECOS=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f5)
  homedir=$(echo "$line" | cut -d: -f6)
  echo "adduser -g '$GECOS' -d '$homedir' -s /bin/bash '$username'"
done < "new_users.txt"
```

### Here's where I'm struggling

The code above pretty much displays the information in the `new_users.txt` file
I'm struggling on the second part, my code is posted below:
What I want to do is create a script that generates the `cs.rosters.txt` file like I did above.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
user=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2)
pass=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3)
home=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4)

useradd -m -d $home -s /bin/bash $user
echo $pass | passwd --stdin $user
done < cs_roster.txt
```

I'm getting two errors: one is saying the Computer directory is invalid and the function `--stdin` is invalid. Can you help me?

Comment: Please paste your second script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: As the bash tag you added tells you to do `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here.` and if you still have a problem afterwards then copy/paste exactly the error messages you're getting into your question.

Comment: Can you post a sample `cs_roster.txt` that duplicates the problem?

Comment: if your `passwd` doesn't have `--stdin` you probably have to use `chpasswd` instead: `echo -n "$user:$pass" | chpasswd`

Comment: In your case you have two entries with `0510` you are attempting to use as `home` in `useradd -m -d $home -s /bin/bash $user`. On the second `useradd` naming the directory for an existing user will be invalid.

Comment: Also, you want to avoid calling utilities within loops in shell if at all possible. Highly inefficient. Bash provides all the tools you need to separate the values directly with `read`. For example you can do `while IFS=$'|\n' read -r course user fullname n1 n2 || [ -n "$n1" ]; do ... your code here ... done < "$infile"` Here each of the wanted variables will be in `course`, `user`, `fullname` and `n1` and `n2` (note: `n2` isn't provided on your second line so the test `[ -n "$n2" ]` was chosen. No utilities required at all.

Comment: @eggs you can provide `printf "course: %s\nuser: %s\nfullname: %s\nn1: %s\nn2: %s\n" "$course" "$user" "$fullname" "$n1" "$n2"` in the loop and see how are the variables are separated.

Comment: I got it running! Thank you! @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: The `IFS` is the (*Internal Field Separator*) that controls word-splitting. You want the lines split on `'|'` and `'\n'`, so just set `IFS` to that. The default `IFS` is `$' \t\n'` (space tab newline). It makes splitting text into fields simple -- and much more efficient.

Comment: _create a script that generates the cs.rosters.txt file_ This contradicts what you are posting. There is nothing in this script which would **generate** (i.e. write to) cs_rosters.txt. In contrary, your script already assumes the existensce of this file.